# Display all e-mails with certain category in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, vba7

I would like to create a macro that will display all e-mails in certain category. So far I am using

```
    Sub GDPR()
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application 
txtSearch = "category:=(""Personal Data"")"
myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders 
Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

it works but a bit strange, because it also shows an  e-mails without any category, but including Personal Data in the body.
I thought that the `category:=` syntax is special for categories only, and by using it only categorized e-mail will be returned.

Any better method to achive that apart using search function macro?

Answer (score 0):

The `Search` method accepts a search string that can contain any valid keywords supported in `Instant Search`. It behaves as if the user has typed the query string in the Instant Search user interface and then clicked Search. Do you get the same results on the UI in Outlook?

When calling `Search`, the query is run in the user interface, and there is no programmatic mechanism to obtain the search results. For more information on Instant Search, query for "Instant Search" in the Outlook Help. Moreover, the `Search` method does not provide a callback to enable the developer to determine when the search is complete.

I'd suggest using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class instead. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.
- Ability to save results to the search folder, so the results will be visible in the Outlook UI.
- You will be notified when the search process is completed.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Also, if you don't need to show results in the UI, you may consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. You can read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need I guess. The advanced search.  What I need now is a macro, that will automatically open advanced search window with predefined query like this: Categories is exactly Personal data.